# How to know if a user can book a room on Office 365 from graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to know if a user has the right to book a meeting room with the Graph API?

I need to book rooms from my backend. Today, if the user does not have the right to book the room, he receives a rejection email.
I would like to check his authorization before booking from the graph api.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can call [getSchedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint to get the free/busy availability information for a collection of users, distributions lists, or resources (rooms or equipment) for a specified time period.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getSchedule
```

In request body specify the rooms you want to book and the date, time, and time zone that the period starts and ends.

```
{
    "schedules": [
        "MeetingRoom534@xxx.com",
        "MeetingRoom535@xxx.com"
    ],
    "startTime": {
        "dateTime": "2022-06-02T01:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Central Europe Standard Time"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "dateTime": "2022-06-02T18:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Central Europe Standard Time"
    },
    "availabilityViewInterval": 60
}
```

The response will contain a collection of [scheduleInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/scheduleinformation?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: I made a test and it doesn't work. GraphApi returns availability for all rooms even if user does not have permissions to book it